# Ubuntu 8.04 fine; Ubuntu 16.04 video messed up - why, how to fix?

Tags: linux

I've got a used windows machine, [HP Pavilion,AMD PHENOM X3 8550 triple core, 3GB, NVIDIA 6150 SE, vista home premium] that was given up for an unreadable screen (looks like scan-lines are horizontally unstable).  The blue boot-up screens are ok. Ubuntu 8.04 LiveDVD boots up just fine, so the graphics card must be fine. But Ubuntu 16.04 boots with the same unreadable screen.

Probably not relevent, but I'll mention it anyway: the NTFS is unmountable (something about possible corrupted journal, or bad soft/fake RAID settings, or other vague descriptions).

How can one version be fine and another not?  Is there a way to get 16.04 stable?

Comment: Just try `Ubuntu Mate`. https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/

Comment: The actual video drivers.  You may be dealing with the `nv` driver, the `nouveau` driver, or nvidia's proprietary binary blob driver.  FWIW the nouveau isn't that good and is known to cause issues.